# C: Why is counter not resetting to 0 in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, counter

So Im creating a simple `for loop` within a `for loop`. The var `frequecyCount` is not resetting to 0, don't understand why.

I have going through to arrays x and hist array and need  a counter variable to count the frequency of the same value in x as the position of hist.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 void  create_hist(double *x, int count, int *hist) {
    int frequencyCount = 0;
    for (int iHist = 0; iHist <= 5; iHist++) {
        //initalize to zero
        hist[iHist] = 0;

        for (int ix = 0; ix < count; ix++) {
            // convert to int
            x[ix] = (int)x[ix];

            if (x[ix] == hist[iHist]) {
                frequencyCount++;
            }
        }
        // add to the hist[] array the frequency count at position i
        hist[iHist] = frequencyCount;
        frequencyCount = 0;
    }

    int main( void ) {
    double x[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 3};
    int hist[5];
    int count = 5; 

    create_hist(x, count, hist);

    printf( "\tInput data:\n" );
    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        printf( "\t%d\t%f\n", i, x[i] );
    }

    printf( "\tHistogram:\n" );
    for ( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
        printf( "\t%d\t%d\n", i, hist[i] );
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have tried. I've tried to set the counter to 0, tested the for loop is working correctly, no success!

Comment: Why did you write the code like that anyway? Declare `frequencyCount` inside the outer loop. Instead of declaring it in the outer scope, because you will only use it inside the loop. But it doesn't make sense what you say. Also, show a declaration/definition of `hist`  and `x` please.

Comment: `x[ix] = (int)x[ix];` What.

Comment: Hey I've added the main function so you can see the declaration. Please let me know if you have any idea what the problem is

Comment: Posting `main()` is much less useful than posting a compilable function for `create_hist()` (which I presume your original code is *part of*).

Comment: The loop control `iHist <= 5;` breaks the array `int hist[5];` So in the function, `hist[iHist] = 0;` is *undefined behaviour* after which anything might happen.

Answer (score 2):

Try this change:

```
for (int iHist = 0; iHist < 5; iHist++) {  // <= changed to <
    int frequencyCount = 0;                // Moved this line to be inside the loop
```

Answer (score 2):

The `frequencyCount` variable is resetting. There is another reason your output is not what you expect.

This `if` statement is most likely wrong:

```
    if (x[ix] == hist[iHist]) {
        frequencyCount++;
    }
```

At this stage, `hist[iHist]` is always `0` (that's the value you assigned just before the loop).

I think you mean:

```
    if (x[ix] == iHist) {
        frequencyCount++;
    }
```

You also need to change the loop range condtion from `i <= 5` to `i < 5` in `main` and from `iHist <= 5` to `iHist < 5` in `create_hist` to avoid buffer overflow.

Making these changes results in the output:

```
    Input data:
    0       0.000000
    1       0.000000
    2       0.000000
    3       0.000000
    4       3.000000
    Histogram:
    0       4
    1       0
    2       0
    3       1
    4       0
```